# S3 Bucket policy does not work when request is redirected to S3 bucket via servlet

Tags: java, nginx, amazon-s3, servlets

1. We have a java servlet application which  redirects the request to s3 bucket html file like,

```
String htmlURL = "https://s3_bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/118/vtour/tour.html";
resp.sendRedirect(url);
```

2. The servlet application is deployed on tomcat server and all these network configuration is maintained via nginx proxy pass. nginx is running on different machine. Nginx config as:

```
    location /JavaServletApp {
         proxy_pass  http://ip_address_of_tomcat_server:8080;
    }
```

On s3 we added bucket policies to allow access for specific ip address only as follows: (Ideally we would like to set the sourceIP as that of nginx server only). The tomcat server shall not be publicly reachable)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1576643187337",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1576643184762",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::s3_bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "nginx_server_ip",
                        "tomcat_server_public_ip",
                        "tomcat_server_private_ip",
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Note: S3 bucket is public.

If we try to render s3 html file via https://nginx/JavaServlet app, it is giving "Access Denied" error.However, if we hit the s3 bucket html file directly(without servlet application) from the nginx server via curl then that html file get rendered.

And if we add ip address of the local laptop (public gateway IP) to s3 bucket policy, then if we hit https://nginx/JavaServlet app, the html on S3 is rendered. But this is not a viable solution.

Also, tried setting Referer as nginx-host, in the nginx configuration, we still cannot access the html on S3 via https://nginx/JavaServlet app.

[image: Workflow]

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/block-s3-traffic-vpc-ip/
Is this solve your problem?

Comment: you can also try IAM policies to allow you IPs

Comment: If you *redirect* to the bucket, then (of course) the browser's IP address is the one that S3 will see because the browser connects to the bucket directly.  To me, it is unclear what are you actually attempting to accomplish, by access-controlling a public bucket, and why?

Answer (score 0):

As @Michel said, since you use:

```
resp.sendRedirect(url);
```

The bucket will receive a request from the client's browser, so you can't apply a good policy for it.

The AWS way to handle this situation is to use a [GeneratePresignedURL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/java-s3-src-main-java-GeneratePresignedURL.java.html) and redirect the client to the generated URL.